# Is the radiation exposure in a spacecraft window seat significantly different than other areas of the cabin?

Tags: radiation, health, spacecraft-window

Does an astronaut seated next to a window get more exposure to harmful radiation (and if so, which types of radiation) than an astronaut somewhere else in the cabin at the same time?

Related:

- [Is exposure to cosmic radiation more dangerous on some body parts than on other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10752/26446)
- [Does the ISS medical inventory include a sun-tan/sunscreen lotion/cream?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5508/26446)
- [When estimating radiation doses inside a lunar habitat, what assumptions are made as to shape?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15091/26446)
- [Why can't we use the same radiation shielding in Mars that we used when going to the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22045/26446)

Comment: More radiation in the visible light portion of the spectrum, certainly... 

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I've just added the word "harmful" to the question.

Comment: windows may be thicker (in [radiation lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_length)) than spacecraft skin thickness, so it could be more, or less, or inconsequential.

Comment: The major radiation of concern tends to be protons and electrons from the sun, which are shielded better by low-Z materials than dense materials like lead because of the secondary x-rays. Glass is silicon and oxygen, which are both low on the periodic table, not far from aluminum and carbon. The hull is probably aluminum, maybe with layers of Kevlar (H, C, N, O) and Nextel (Al, O, B, Si). Not actually that different. See: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/what-materials-are-the-windows-on-the-us-segment-of-the-iss-made-out-of